# How to access typescript object property from a string?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In typescript I have this object of type "Eular" (from three.js library). The object has 3 properties I can access `x`, `y`, `z`, like this

```
obj.z = 1;
```

But suppose I have this now

```
var key = "z";
```

How can I access the `z` property from using the variable `key`?

This doesn't work

```
obj[key] = 1;
```

I get this

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Euler'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Euler'.ts(7053)
```

Thanks

Comment: Either use `const` instead (I'd highly recommend always using `const`), or narrow the string key to one of the permitted properties first

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Have you not really heard of `const` before?

Comment: I use it, but don't know how to use it for this question.

Comment: Hint TypeScript that `key` is a key of `obj`, i.e. `const key: keyof typeof obj = "z";`